# Daphnis Nerii not moving

Tags: entomology, development

Its been quite a while since my *Daphnis Nerii* has passed its eating phase, now its just a sort of recluse and is curled up in one corner and sleeps the whole day. It's a bit brownish in colour now. Although when I check on it, by lifting the container and moving it about, it starts jumping oddly. Like a jumpstart,  everytime it gets provoked. It maybe is the last phase of its instar period. Is it getting ready to pupate? Or is it not well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daphnis_nerii) tells us the following about the larva of the oleander hawk-moth (*Daphnis Nerii*):

> Just before it pupates, the oleander hawk-moth larva becomes browner in color. The pupa of this species measures around 5.5 to 7.5 centimeters in length, and is light brown with black spots and a black line down the middle

The stage your critter is in probably resembles Fig. 1. It's probably fine.

[image: D nerii]
<sup>Fig. 1. Caterpillar just before pupating. source: [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daphnis_nerii)</sup>

Comment: But the problem is that its quite inactive. Do caterpillars tend to stay inactive in pre-pupation?